# enum Python how to response

Tags: python, django

Are there any ways to display status_choices in model.py type string in Postman?

my model.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    status_choices = (
        (1, 'in processing'),
        (2, 'in delivery'),
        (3, 'done'),
        (4, 'cancel'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_choices)
    total = models.BigIntegerField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variant, through='TransactionVariant')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "transaction"
```

serializer.py

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # status = StatusSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    transaction_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
    product = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    status =  serializers.CharField()
    address = serializers.CharField()
    total = serializers.IntegerField()
    phone_number = serializers.IntegerField()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%H:%M %d %b %Y')
```

my response in postman:

```
 "user_id": 5,
    "transaction_id": 1,
    "product": "product1",
    "status": "3",----------> I want this field return what exactly in my model designer
    "address": "trung nu vuong 3",
    "total": 123,
    "phone_number": 1234567890,
    "created_at": "09:35 21 Jan 2019"
```

I want response return

```
{
status: done
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SerializerMethodField

```
status = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_status_as_char")

def get_status_as_char(self, obj):
   return  obj.get_status_display()
```

Comment: Can share your code(Serializer) after you implemented my solution.

Comment: @PhuTranV2 Would changing the integers to strings in the choices tuple list help? E.g. `(1, 'in processing'),` to `('1', 'in processing'),`. Your db field is char, yet the mapping uses integers. And the @AtleyVarghese solution should work.

Comment: nice, it worked for me :D  thank you both of you @mfrackowiak, Atley